# Webpack: Loading images from html templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to set up an angular project using Webpack but I can't figure out how to reference images from within html templates and have them included in the build.

My project tree is as follows:

```
package.json
app/
- images/
  - foo.png
- scripts/
- styles/
- templates/
```

I'm trying to use `html-loader` along with `url-loader` and `file-loader` but it's just not happening.

This is an example template: `app/templates/foo.html`

```
<img src="../images/foo.png" />
```

**Problem #1**: I would like to be able to reference images relative to `app/`. Right now, the paths need to be relative to the template file and this will get ugly very quickly (`../../../images/foo.png`).

**Problem #2**: Even if I specify the relative path, as I have done above, the project builds successfully but nothing really happens. The paths are left as-is and no images appear in `dist/`.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ngminPlugin = require('ngmin-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ngAnnotatePlugin = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = function(config, env) {
  var appRoot = path.join(__dirname, 'app/')
  if(!env) env = 'development';
  var webpackConfig = {
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    contentBase: appRoot,
    entry: {
      app: path.join(appRoot, '/scripts/app.coffee')
    },

    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/),
      publicPath: '/',
      libraryTarget: 'var',
      filename: 'scripts/[name].[hash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=./node_modules/foundation/scss/')
        },
        {
          test: /\.coffee$/,
          loader: 'coffee-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, './app')) + '/!html'
        },
        {
          test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=image/png&name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]"
        },
        {
          test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?(.*))?$/,
          loader: 'url?prefix=factorynts/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
        },
        {
          test: /\.ttf(\?(.*))?$/,
          loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/'
        },
        {
          test: /\.eot(\?(.*))?$/,
          loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/'
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg(\?(.*))?$/,
          loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/'
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json'
        }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: [
        '',
        '.js',
        '.coffee',
        '.scss',
        '.css'
      ],
      root: [appRoot],
    },

    singleRun: true,
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/.*$/, /a^/),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '_': 'lodash'
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].[chunkhash].css", {allChunks: true}),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: appRoot + '/app.html',
        filename: 'app.html',
        inject: 'body',
        chunks: ['app']
      })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
  }

  if(env === 'production') {
    webpackConfig.plugins = webpackConfig.plugins.concat(
      new ngAnnotatePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process-env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    );
    webpackConfig.devtool = false;
    webpackConfig.debug = false;
  }
  return webpackConfig;
```

}

Comment: How did you solve problem #1?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Yes, you will have to do so for loading images from different path.
2. I had similar issue and I resolved this using `file` loader:

.

```
loaders: [{
  // JS LOADER
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}, {
  // ASSET LOADER
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader'
},
{
  //IMAGE LOADER
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  loader:'file-loader'
},
{
  // HTML LOADER
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader'
},
{
  //SCSS LOADER
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader?indentedSyntax"]
}
]
```

Good Luck

Comment: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders. You need to specify 'file-loader' instead of 'file'.

Comment: Not sure how this solves @syko's as it looks like the same setup he has.   Are there any `file-loader` options that will allow to simple have html files reference a common reference point (even @syko app folder is a start), so one could do `<img src="./images/foo.png">`, since the directory structure of images is less likely to change than many template files.   Luis's answer below is most correct, since module aliasing can also be used, but adding in the require looks ugly and not very intuitive.

Comment: @GuyPark if you want the equivalent to `<img src="./images/foo.png">` with file-loader, you can import the image from your .js file and add it to your template via raw javascript code.

Comment: A nice touch, but unfortunately this is a dynamic image loaded from an [authenticated] API service, so it's a bit more tricky, otherwise I would.  :)

Answer (score 37):

If you are using HTML templates in Webpack 2, in addition to use the file-loader you need to change in your HTML:

`<img src="../images/foo.png" />`

to this

`<img src=<%=require("../images/foo.png")%> />`

Comment: What if i previously had <img src="images/icons/<%= type %>-m.png"/> ? How do i dynamically import ?

Comment: Result: `<img src="[object" module]=""`, or `<img src="[object Module]"` with quotes

Comment: @ArthurShlain `<img src=<%=require("../images/foo.png").default%> />` reference `.default` to the method call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070216/webpack-file-loader-outputs-object-module

Comment: URIError: Failed to decode param '/%3C%=require(%22../assets/eotpeccy.png%22).default%'

Answer (score 11):

For Webpack 5 you have to write this way:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    // other stuff above.....
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'html-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The sources options defaults to true, so this might not be so helpful https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/

Answer (score 5):

With Webpack 4, I was able to solve this problem by updating by `html-loader` to specify the `root` for my files.  So given @syko's original structure; in `webpack.config.js`...

```
module: {
  rules: [
    // other stuff above.....
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      use: [
        // ...The other file-loader and extract-loader go here.
        {
          loader: 'html-loader'
          options: {
            // THIS will resolve relative URLs to reference from the app/ directory
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This tells the `html-loader` to interpret all *absolute* urls from the `/app` folder.  So in our `app/templates/foo.html`, you can then use the following...

```
<img src="/images/foo.png" />
```

This then tells `html-loader` to see the above as `path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'images', 'foo.png')`.  Then if you have `extract-loader` and/or `file-loader`, all the paths should be correct.

Managed to get this solution after hammering away at it for a while.  The biggest confusion is where about in the loader stack the `/images/foo.png` is interpreted, in this case it starts at the `html-loader` plugin.   Everything else after that, is more about how the image files are to be published.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In addition to above `url-loader` needed es6 modules to be disabled through option `esModule: false`

Comment: any idea what is its alternative for webpack 5 ?

Comment: Sorry couldn't say.  Only needed this on an old project (no longer maintain) that used it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) to extract images. Then using [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) you can specify which tag-attribute combination should be processed by this loader via the query parameter `attrs`.

I could make it work with this configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'images/'
        }
    }]
},
{
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
            attrs: ['img:src', 'link:href']
        }
    }
}
```

Or in angular something like this:

```
attrs: [':ng-src', ':ng-href']
```