# How to use <img src> in webpack?

Tags: webpack

When I'm trying to load an image

```
<img class="brand" alt="Brand" width="50%" height="50%" src="/logo.jpg">
```

It produces the following error:

> logo.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module: {   
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            exclude: /index\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader?root=./assets/images&interpolate&name=./views/[name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=./assets/images/[name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack: Loading images from html templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753650/webpack-loading-images-from-html-templates)

Answer (score 10):

You have to `import/require` your image in your `entry js` file and that image will be processed and added to your `output` directory and the `Logo` variable will contain the url of that image after processing

```
import Logo from './logo.jpg';
```

Another way is to use `html-loader` and import it  in your `entry js` file . Then you can use the usual `src` attribute as in html.