# Webpack file-loader outputs [object Module]

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am using webpack with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, `html-loader` and `file-loader`. I have a simple project structure in which I use no frameworks, but only typescript. Thus, I write my HTML code directly to `index.html`. I also use this HTML file as my template in `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

As all websites do I need to put an image which refers to a PNG in my assets folder. `file-loader` should load the file correctly put the new filename inside the `src` tag but that is not what is happening. Instead, as the value of `src` tag, I have `[object Module]`. I assume the `file-loader` emits some object and it is represented like this when its `.toString()` method is run. However, I can see that `file-loader` has processed the file successfully and emitted with new name to the output path. I get no errors.  Here is my webpack configuration and `index.html`.

```
const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

{
  entry: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src', 'app.ts'),
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|png)$/i,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src', 'index.html')
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css',
      ignoreOrder: false
    })
  ]
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="dark">
    <header>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="assets/logo.png" class="logo"> <!-- This logo is output as [object Module] -->
        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Project structure:

```
config/
    webpack.config.js
dist/
src/
    styles/
    assets/
        logo.png
    index.html
    app.ts
```

**Edit**
My package.json dependencies:

```
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"css-loader": "^3.2.0",
"file-loader": "^5.0.2",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"style-loader": "^1.0.0",
"ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
"typescript": "^3.7.2",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Per the file-loader [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#esmodule):

> By default, file-loader generates JS modules that use the ES modules syntax. There are some cases in which using ES modules is beneficial, like in the case of module concatenation and tree shaking.

It seems that webpack resolves ES module `require()` calls to an object that looks like this: `{default: module}`, instead of to the flattened module itself. This behavior is somewhat controversial and is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4742).

Therefore, to get your `src` attribute to resolve correctly, you need to be able to access the `default` property of the exported module. If you're using a framework, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<img src={require('assets/logo.png').default}/> <!-- React -->
<!-- OR -->
<img src="require('assets/logo.png').default"/> <!-- Vue -->
```

Alternatively, you can enable file-loader's CommonJS module syntax, which webpack will resolve directly to the module itself. Set `esModule:false` in your webpack config.

webpack.config.js:

```
 {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Comment: That worked. However it is still little bit magic. If you have ideas about why this is the case could you also explain it in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Bora -- Did a little more research and updated answer.

Comment: This bit me during an update from `Angular 8` to `Angular 9` as that brought `file-loader` from version `4.2.0` to `6.0.0`. Using `require(...).default` fixed it for me.

Comment: I encountered this after upgrading file-loader.  Looking more carefully at the changelog, I see the default value for esModule changed to true with version 5.0.0.

Comment: With react 16.13.1 i faced the same issue where require was not working Using require(...).default fixed it for me

Comment: Thank you soooo much for pointing out the esModule: false flag. I couldn't for the life of me figure out why my js was handling my image fine, but my scss was returning an object module instead. I spent hours on this!

Comment: Using require(...).default is worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

@stellr42's suggested fix of `esModule: false` in your `file-loader` configuration is the best workaround at the current time.

However, this is actually a bug in `html-loader` which is being tracked here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/203

It looks like ES Module support was added to `file-loader`, `css-loader`, and other friends, but `html-loader` was missed.

Once this bug is fixed, it will be better to remove `esModule: false` and simply upgrade `html-loader`, as ES Modules offer some minor benefits (as mentioned in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#esmodule))

Alternatively, if (like me), you found this issue because you were having trouble loading an image *from CSS* (instead of from HTML), then the fix is just to upgrade `css-loader`, no need to disable ES Modules.

Comment: Finally, someone who faced the same problem! But as of 07/2022, I still need to set `esModule: false` in my Webpack config in order to see my .svg displayed, even with `css-loader 6.7.0` in my dev dependencies. Any clue?

Comment: as of today 04/2023, i still need this esModule: false :/ with file-loader:6.2.0

Answer (score 8):

Just updated my file-loader to ^5.0.2 minutes ago.

I know `esModule: false` was the suggested fix but that did not work for me.

My fix was `<img src={require('assets/logo.png').default}/>` which was weird. First time using `.default` but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

This happens on file-loader version 5.0.2 , earlier version works fine without calling `default` property

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this: `<img src="require('assets/logo.png').default"/>`

Use it like this: `<img src={require('assets/logo.png').default}/>`

Comment: it is the best approach

Answer (score 3):

Use "default" followed by require to display a dynamic image in react js

src={require('../images/'+image_name+'.png').default}

Answer (score 1):

For **Next.JS**:

```
// require(...).default.src
<img src={require("../public/images/avatar.png").default.src} width={256} height={256} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem recently after upgrading Laravel Mix v4 to v6.
This works fine with me in my Vue component.

```
<img :src="require('./assets/profile.png').default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in vuejs and `esModule:false` did not work for me.
Instead, I used @kerubim solution and it fixed it, but only in production mode and in development mode I get some error.

So I wrote this function in `util.js` that solved my problem.

```
maybeDefault: (module) => {

  if (typeof module === "object") {

    module = module.default;
  }

  return module;
},
```

use example:

```
let logo = 'logo.svg';
util.maybeDefault(require(`img/svg/logos/${logo}`));
```

Comment: @Dharman sorry, I think it's clear, so yeah. I used this function and solved my problem.
but in `vuejs`, and of course it's can used for other purposes.

Comment: This worked for me in Gatsby without having to rewrite the webpack config

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue still unsure how mine got fixed.

So I deleted my `node_module` and `package-lock.json` and ran `npm install --force`

and it worked fine after

Answer (score 0):

for webpack 5 you need to use, [Type option:](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)

```
{
   test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|svg)$/i,
   type: 'asset/resource',
},
```