# require function not working with image in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image

I've used `<img src={require('./somRelativePath/image.jpg)}` in React many times. However, this time it seems not to be working. There are no errors whatsoever (such as that the image was not found etc.) but the broken image on website.

After inspecting the element I was somewhat confused by the transpiled result in browser:

```
<img src="[object Module]" style="width: 5rem;">
```

It appears as if it loads the image as a component not the acutual file. I've created the app with `npx create-react-app` and haven't ejected it so far. So there is no error in babel or webpack configuration as it is currently handled by react under the hood.

Importing it with `import` statement works just fine:

```
import calendarPic from '../assets/pictures/calendar.svg';
```

Unfortunately that's not the solution because I have the local images saved in json and it would be definitely quite repetitive and ineffective as well to load all 50 images.

With the same `npx create-react-app` I've made a handful of mini-projects before but have never come across such a perplexing, yet so basic error. I'd be so thankful for any response as I've skimmed every possible solution throughout the internet.

Thank you again and have a lovely day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070216/webpack-file-loader-outputs-object-module)

Comment: Well I do not have access to the .webpack configuration file as it's handled by react, so I'd have to eject it. Do you recommend that @Darkshadow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the problem is the location of the image. When you use `create-react-app` the app will be bundle into the `public` folder. Then the `require` statement would start to fetch the image - in this case in relative to the `public` folder and not to the `src` folder.

What I suggest you to do is try to move the image into the `public` folder and try using the `src` with URL relative to the `public` folder. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-feather-cc64n?file=/src/App.js) here

Comment: Yeah, that is bound to work. Do you use it this way every time you code React app?

Comment: I usually use the `import Image from './source/` because I don't use a lot of image. Read more about the tradeoff between those two methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js)

Answer (score 33):

use this one, it's work for me

`<img src={require('./somRelativePath/image.jpg').default}`

---

Explanation :

Value from `let image1require('./somRelativePath/image.jpg')` is different with
`import calendarPic from './somRelativePath/image.jpg';`

If you console them, value from `calendarPic` is a path, but if you use `require`, the value is an object [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d1NE.png).

Comment: Thanks man, I've struggled with this issue for a while now, I always ended up using alternative methods that I felt didn't work too well for me.

Comment: add `.default` and it's working..thx man

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me. Instead I used `require(path)` outside the `img` tag and assigned it into a variable, then used the variable inside the `img` tag `src`. It works that way.

```
const F = {
  name: "Weiß",
  image: require('./images/0453-Eastbourne-F961-F01.png')
}
```

Inside the image tag:

```
src = { F.image }
```