# Howler sound getting stuck in queue

Tags: reactjs, audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

I have a `Howl` wherein I trigger the `play()` method on button click, but the sound still doesn't play. If I log the `Howl` instance to the console on button click, I san see that the play events are queued up in the object's `queue` prperty, and the `state` is `"loading"`.

I tried looking through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074222/howler-wont-load-and-play-sound-files) but had no luck. I've also moved the assets around from src to public, tried different file formats, different priorities of formats etc.

Here's my code so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Howl } from "howler";

export default function Sounds() {
  const soundEffects = new Howl({
    src: ["effects.webm", "effects.mp3"],
    sprite: {
      loop: [0, 60.013492063492066],
      deepSounds: [62, 266.4691383219955],
      screwdriver: [268, 293.9140589569161],
    },
  });

  const handleLoopPlay = () => {
    console.log(soundEffects);
    soundEffects.play("loop");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLoopPlay}>Play loop</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The sprite looks like this:

```
{
  "resources": [
    "effects.webm",
    "effects.mp3"
  ],
  "spritemap": {
    "loop": {
      "start": 0,
      "end": 60.013492063492066,
      "loop": false
    },
    "deepSounds": {
      "start": 62,
      "end": 266.4691383219955,
      "loop": false
    },
    "screwdriver": {
      "start": 268,
      "end": 293.9140589569161,
      "loop": false
    }
  }
}
```

And the project directory:

[image: Folder directory]

Also, I'm getting Chrome' `AudioContext` warning, and I'm not sure why because I'm indeed waiting for user interaction before playing:

```
The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
```