# Module not found: You attempted to import which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have just started React JS, but I have a problem and despite my research I can not get results, I have tried many ways, but I have not been able to solve this problem.Can you help ?

this is the error I got at the terminal

```
./src/App.css (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/images/img-8.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

- Node Version : v12.18.3
- Npm Version : 6.14.8

---

**My File Structure**

```
- node_modules
 - public
     * images
          * img-2.jpg
     * videos

 - src
    * App.js
    * App.css
    * index.js
    * setupTest.js
```

---

**the picture i am trying to import in my css file**

```
background-image: url('/public/images/img-2.jpg');
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
   <Router>
     <Navbar></Navbar>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact />
     </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
 {
      "name": "react-website",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
        "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `/images/img-2.jpg/` to refer to the folder. The reason is that you are using `create-react-app` to create this React app. When being bundled the app will be located in the `public` folder. Read this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910839/require-function-not-working-with-image-in-react/64911131#64911131) where it mentions the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an image, this one will work in your src/ directory

```html
            <img src={"/images/img-2.jpg"} alt=""/>
```

try to use this in your src/ directory

```html
background-image: url('../public/images/img-2.jpg');
```