# Require doesn't work in react but img src={logo} work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understund why the first one works, and the second one doesn't work.()

```js
import logo from './navigation/singapour.jpg';
```

```js
<img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
<img src={require('./navigation/singapour.jpg')} />
```

Comment: Which one fail? The first `<img>` or the second? If it's the second read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910839/require-function-not-working-with-image-in-react/64911131#64911131)

Comment: make sure that your image is insie the src diretry

Comment: The second fail <img src={require('./navigation/singapour.jpg')} />.