# Javascript Require Image vs Import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

import avatar from './assets/images/2020-avatar.png'

function App() {
  return (
      <Container>
        <Avatar src={avatar} />
        <Medium src={require("./assets/images/medium_512.png")} />
      </Container>
    );
  }

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
`;
;

const Avatar = styled.img`
  top: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 583px;
  object-fit: contain;
`;

const Medium = styled.img`
  top: 475px;
  left: 475px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: contain;
`;


export default App;
```

All of the references I've seen regarding the `require()` statement should work for the `medium_512.png` image, but it shows as a broken image. Only the imported `avatar` image works.

Wondering what I'm doing wrong here and why all the examples I've seen using require I have similar syntax, but obviously something is wrong.

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910839/require-function-not-working-with-image-in-react/64911131#64911131

Comment: A couple of things, Require isn't an in-built function in js, it has to be added in or it automatically works when running the code with node. Because of this, webpack doesn't always require the file correctly.

Secondly, imports and requires happen at the beginning so having it nested within code may be causing the issue.

Comment: @kunquan have right. but you can try with dynamic import.

Comment: I had tried placing the files in the public directory, but they were broken as well (even though no errors were shown on the console). In looking at the answer posted above, I adjusted my link. I had `../public/images/Avatar.png` and just needed to remove "public" to be `../images/Avatar.png` as "public" as a top level was already loaded. :(