# How to call display image from local JSON using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a React demo project for learning purposes. But I am stuck.
I have added the image in the JSON file and I have called the image in the blog page but there is a problem with the image path. please check the below screenshot and please review my code to placode page URL please review. https://playcode.io/dhavalpatel

Blog page : https://prnt.sc/WwIxG6cntBeF

**Blog page Code blog.js**

```
{data.map((user) => {
    return(
        <div className="artical--wrap" key={user.id}>
            <div className="blog-content">
                <img src={user.imgpath} />
                <h2>{user.title}</h2>
            </div>
       </div>
   )
})}
```

**Json file code screenshort**
https://prnt.sc/K27wu7y_fINV

Comment: Dhaval Patel, Use <img src={require(`../${user.imgpath}`).default}/> instead of <img src={user.imgpath} />

Comment: You need to use require, see reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910839/require-function-not-working-with-image-in-react

Comment: @ShanthiB - I have added but not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community Please check this url -- https://playcode.io/dhavalpatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use require keyword in your code as I mentioned in demo code:

**Here is the demo:**

**=> Change your data.json this way:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Blog Title 1",
    "imgpath": "award1.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Blog Title 2",
    "imgpath": "award1.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Blog Title 3",
    "imgpath": "award1.png"
  }
]
```

**=> Change your blog.js this way:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import InnerBanner from "../components/innerbanner";
import Blog from "../components/blog";

import data from "../data.json";

// Blog Post images
import Blog1 from "../images/service1.png";
import Blog2 from "../images/service2.png";
import Blog3 from "../images/service3.png";

const BlogData = [
  {
    BlogImage: Blog1,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "19 Nov 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog2,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "10 Nov 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog3,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "09 Nov 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog1,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "01 Nov 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog2,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "19 March 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog3,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "29 Oct 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog1,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "24 Oct 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog2,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "20 Oct 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
  {
    BlogImage: Blog3,
    BlogTitle: "Blog Title",
    BlogDate: "19 Oct 2018 / Super User",
    BlogContent:
      "Sample text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam nunc justo sagittis suscipit ultrices.",
    BlogUrl: "/blog",
  },
];
async function loadImage(imgPath) {
  const x = await import(`../${imgPath}`);
  return x.default;
}
function Blogpage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
  return (
    <div className="blogpage">
      <InnerBanner PageTitle="Blog page" />

      <section className="blog--section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="flex-container">
            {data.map((user) => {
              console.log(user);
              return (
                <div className="artical--wrap" key={user.id}>
                  <div className="blog-content">
                    <img
                      src={require(`../images/${user.imgpath}`)}
                      alt="Blog Image"
                    />

                    <h2>{user.title}</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="blog--section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="flex-container">
            {BlogData.map((item, index) => (
              <Blog
                BlogImage={item.BlogImage}
                BlogTitle={item.BlogTitle}
                BlogDate={item.BlogDate}
                BlogContent={item.BlogContent}
                BlogUrl={item.BlogUrl}
                key={item.BlogTitle + index}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Blogpage;
```

**Explanation:**

The require keyword needed when you try to fetch the image from `src` folder - If you want to use the relative path than put images into `public` folder.

**Additional Note:** require can't fetch dynamic path, instead you need to pass image name as a string in predefined path.

Let me know, If you've any questions.

Comment: I have added this code. but it's not working

Comment: Hey, I have fixed your example. Check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but still shows an error. please refer to the screenshot. --- 
 https://prnt.sc/doW7k6NO8b2c

Comment: I think you haven't changed data.json, Please make changes as I mentioned in my answer. Here is output: https://prnt.sc/WkxzGDUTaZB1

Comment: I understand. It is working on your local server but it is not working on my server.