# file-loader require returns [object Module]

Tags: vue.js, webpack, file-loader

I'm using `"file-loader": "^6.2.0"` in my Vue.js project, and I try to load PNG images from my assets directory using `<img :src="require('@/assets/images/image.png')">`

When image.png is < 4KB it works as expected, but when when it's > 4KB I get a response of `[object Module]`, and I have to add `.default` (`require('@/assets/images/image.png').default`). It's not ideal cause sometimes I don't know the file size in advance, and I also prefer consistent usage "style".

I tried to fix it with [suggestions I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070216/webpack-file-loader-outputs-object-module) , but when I add the `esModule: false` option I get invalid base64 image string(shorter than what I got for images < 4KB before adding the options).

Any suggestion how it can be fixed?